# How to reuse model without creating new one in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm using Hibernate to create table Xtbl in database Ydb in application.

In ***another application***, I want to use the same database and the same table. How can I use it without creating the same model again and without JDBC?

Comment: Just bundle your model classes and config in a jar file, then include that in your new project as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access data from another database table using below annotation in second application.

```
@Table(catalog="app1db")
public class EntityFromApp1{
}
```

you have to make sure that db user of app2 has read access to app1db.

Comment: could you please explain more .

Comment: do i define the column between brackets as in the app1?

Comment: yes what ever property you need from app1 use it, in one of my project i have just copied EntityFromApp1 to app2. and applied @Table annotation.

Comment: i dont want to copy the column in the appl to app2 . Is there another solution to prevent repeat the model

Comment: by mentioning @Table, it will not create new table in app2 database. but instead of that it will refer the same table of app1 database.